# When a solution of a non-linear system exist?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I was trying to solve a problem and end up with the following non-linear system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
a_{11}e^{x_1}+ \ldots+ a_{1n}e^{x_n}=f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}e^{x_1}+\ldots+a_{nn}e^{x_n}=f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
\end{array}\right.$$
where $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. I know that the real matrix $A:=(a_{ij})$ is invertible and I was wandering if this system has real solution. I am searching for methods of solving non-linear system, if somebody could give me some tip about this particular problem I would appreciate very much!

Comment: Insufficient data!  Note that (assuming a real solution is sought) the change of variables $y_k = \log x_k$ would lead to a "quasi-linear" system formulated for positive real solutions.  However more information about the $f_i$ and about matrix $A$ would be necessary to perform significant analysis for the existence of any solutions.

Comment: $A$ is a real matrix and each $f_i$ is a function that has an exponential decay.

Comment: Please say more about this exponential decay.  Also, how do you know $A$ is invertible?  Is it symmetric positive definite?  Is it diagonally dominant?

Comment: For each $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have $|f_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda x_i}$ for some $\lambda<0$. I know that $A$ is invertible because specifics of the problem context. I don't know if is symmetric or diagonal.

Comment: I guess that it is not symmetric ou diagonal.

Comment: The "specifics of the problem" will have to be exposed in order to provide any measure of help.  Is it possible to present a model version of the problem in two unknowns?

Comment: Does the system $Ae^X=0$ have solutions ?

Comment: I am working in a $n$-dimensional kernel of linear operator D that I am identifying with $\mathbb{R}^n$. If I assume that $A$ is not invertible I can produce an element of $\ker D$ that make a contradiction of how these elements look like.

Comment: For each $i=1,\ldots,n$, $f_i=c\langle e_i, g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\rangle$, where $c$ is a constante, $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a base for $\ker D$

Comment: and the only helpful information that I can summarize about $g$ is that $|g| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda x_i}$ for some $\lambda <0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not understand your question, could you please explain to me a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Your system has the form

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
g_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0\\
\vdots\\
g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0
\end{array}\right.$$ and is just a general nonlinear system, for which there is no general method. Unless your $f_n$ have something very special (smoothness tells little).

Comment: What kind of information about $f_n$ would help?

Comment: In my case, $f_n$ are small errors, and when each $x_n \to \infty$ we have $f_n \to 0$, this the only information that a have about them.

Comment: @A.K.O: small compared to what ? Are the $a_{ij}$ of both signs ?

Comment: Yes, the $a_{ij}$ can have both signs and how they are small I explain in the comments of the question above.